# Cypress: find part of a string with cy.contains

Tags: regex, cypress, wildcard

Let's say I have two elements with these texts: "Find a hero" and "Find the hero".

I want to use `cy.contains()` to find one of these, and want to write something like

```js
cy.contains("Find" + * + "hero")
```

I don't understand how I can write this command to find anything that *contains* the two words "Find" and "hero" in a sentence, no matter the order or where they come in.
I'm only using the native cypress (no imported testing libraries, was hoping it won't be necessary).

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Keep in mind, .contains() only returns the first matching DOM element. Does that fit your needs?

Answer (score 3):

The format of `.contains()` to use is a regex parameter, which has "/" delimiters:

```js
cy.contains(/Find .* hero/)
```

The ".*" in the middle means any characters, and any number of characters.

Check out [the example on https://regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pZ8bmC/1).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use `startsWith` and `endsWith`

```js
cy.get(selector)
  .should('satisfy', ($el) => {
    const text = $el.text()
    return text.startsWith('Find') && text.endsWith('hero')
  })
```

This is my **helper function**

```js
const contain = ($el, first, last) => {
  const text = $el.text()
  return text.startsWith(first) && text.endsWith(last)
}

cy.get(selector)
  .should($el => contain($el, 'Find', 'hero'))
```

---

**Double contains**

I don't think anyone mentioned yet, you can use `:contains()` inside `.contains()`

```js
cy.contains(':contains(Find)', 'hero')  // both strings contained
```

Matches the 2nd one:

```html
<div>Find the villain</div>
<div>Find the hero</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex expression to assert that text contain both 'Find' and 'Hero' by doing the following :

```
cy.get('[data-cy=login-button]').invoke('text').should('match', new RegExp('.*Find.*hero', 'gi'));
```

Or your could even do

```
cy.get('YOUR_ELEMENT').should('contains', 'Find').should('contains', 'Hero')
```